# Jump to Closing tag in VS Code?

Tags: tags, key, visual-studio-code, brackets

I can't seem to find a way to select the beginning of a bracket and jump to the end of it through some key combination or something in *VS Code*. For example, in *atom*, this is done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>.

I know there is a way to jump to the beginning and end of a bracket or curlybraces with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> but that does not work for tags. Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing to add to the other answers but I personally prefer `alt+>` because it's kind of related to the angle brackets in tags. But notice, to assign this keybinding, you have to use dot (`.`) instead of `>`, at least these are on the same key on my keyboard. (Also the `alt` key might be called something else such as `meta` in other non-Windows OSs)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

It is possible to do, but either using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> -> "*Emmet: Go to Matching Pair*" or by manually setting a shortcut for it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).

Unfortunately there is currently no support for it out of the box.

Comment: What could be generic format for custom shortcut key in VS code

Comment: FWIW, I set mine to cmd-;

Comment: How do I know what key combinations are available for binding without overwriting any existing bindings? Edit: Oh, nvm. It tells you if it's taken after you type it in.

Comment: ughh just getting "Unable to consume quoted string at char 7028"

Answer (score 62):

You can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>%</kbd> to jump tags in VSCode if you add the following to your `keybindings.json`.

```
{
    "key":"cmd+shift+5",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.matchTag"
}
```

Go to: `File` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` and click the underlined link to edit `keybindings.json`.

For those using VIM keys: you are already used to pressing <kbd>%</kbd> to jump to matching parens and tags. So, hopefully, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>%</kbd> will be close enough to your existing muscle memory to make this transition painless.

Comment: Lol, you're downvoting my answer for that? What you are seeing is a limitation of the VIM plugin you're using. (Try running the emmet command manually.)  It was never a requirement in the question to have it working in visual mode for a specific VIM plugin.

Comment: A big thumbs up for the thought behind maintaining backward compatibility to VIM based matching

Comment: I don't know if it's because I have a newer version, but it wasn't working. I had to wrote: {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+5",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.matchTag",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}

Comment: `ctrl+shift+5` splits the terminal when that's focused. I use `alt+[` for tag matching.

Comment: Is there any support for this now? none of these work for me. using @FrancoisGirard solution. would being in a php/vue file affect this at all...?

Comment: Note there's a bug which prevents this from working if the file contains certain characters https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99896

Comment: I added the line inside the braces: `"when": "editorFocus"`. So, you can use it along with the terminal splits keybinding.

Comment: Note: on a Mac, `cmd+shift+5` triggers screen capturing.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh What should be the alternative then?

Answer (score 16):

For those who are using Vim plugin and Mac, <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> is working well for me.

You can setup in your Vim json file `setting.json` by adding:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
      "before": ["<leader>", "%"],
      "commands": [
        {
          "command": "editor.emmet.action.matchTag"
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

PS. I mentioned Mac user because <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> is for capturing the screen in Mac.

Comment: What is `Leader`? (I use Vim and Mac)

Comment: Ok googled it - though using only `%` is working fine for me.

Comment: Can you get this working in visual mode as well? I added the binding to `visualModeKeyBindings`, but with no luck. I want to be able to select a whole block of HTML from starting to closing tag with `shift + V` to select line where the starting tag is and then `leader + %` to select to the closing tag line.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are asking about [**Breadcrumb Keyboard Navigation**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_breadcrumb-keyboard-navigation)

In this case you can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to go to elements before or after the current element.

Comment: It behaves weird: when I want to stay there in the markup and place the cursor - it throws me back instantly to the end tag :(

Answer (score 5):

You can jump to the matching bracket with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

For more reference, you can refer: [Visual Studio Code Navigation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved)

Answer (score 4):

There is no support for this out of the box. Though if you are willing to use extensions, there is: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag which among other things, gives you ability to use command: `Jump to matching tag` which you can bind to a key.