# Way to view opening tag when closing tag selected in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Looking into using VS Code over PHP Storm and there's one major feature I haven't been able to replicate. Not sure if the community knows of any available plugins or a native way to enable this.

I'm hoping this is the best place to ask, since the VS Code doesn't really have a community section besides recommending asking questions on here.

In PHPStorm when you have your cursor on a closing tag it'll have a little floating line showing you where the opening tag is. Great for knowing exactly what closing tag you're viewing, and it's attributes.

[image: Can see on line 23 despite it being off the screen]

Also, when you're in a tag you can see this down at the bottom, basically the entire tree of where you are.

[image: Can see exactly the nesting structure of the current element]

These are the last few major PHP Storm features I don't think I could live without. If anyone knows of a way to replicate either of them I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The HTML End Tag Labels extension could help you. It shows the id or class, depending on what is given after the closing tag.

[End Tag Labels on VSCode Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=anteprimorac.html-end-tag-labels)

Answer (score 1):

[I tested this in an html and js file but not a php file.]

> // Controls whether the editor should highlight the active indent guide

```
   "editor.highlightActiveIndentGuide": true,
```

> // Controls whether the editor should render indent guides

```
  "editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
```

These are the defaults and then I suggest the following colorCustomizations:

```
"editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#fff8",
"editorIndentGuide.background": "#fff0",
```

The second one above makes all the inactive guides transparent and the first makes the active guide middle grayish.

To highlight the matching tags, see [match tag extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag)

With that extension, try this setting:

```
"highlight-matching-tag.style": {
    "borderWidth": "2px",
    "borderStyle": "solid",
    "borderColor": "red",
    "borderRadius": "5px"
  },
```

[image: active indent guides and tag highlighting]

You will need to reload vscode when you make changes to this extension's settings for them to take effect.

Comment: Ah thanks but I'm looking at highlighting and showing the matching tag even if the matching tags current line is off the screen, like how intelliJ and Atom do.

Comment: Perhaps there is an extension for that, I don't know.  The above might be as close as you can get.  There is also jumping to the other tag, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996522/jump-to-closing-tag-in-vs-code, but that doesn't sound like you want either.