# VS Code jump to matching/closing tag

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, editor, tsx

In Visual Studio Code when the cursor is on a TSX tag I would like to be able to jump to the closing tag, as that might be quite a bit away from the start tag:

```
<MyComponent
  prop1="someValue"
  prop2={someOtherValue}
>
  <OtherComponent1 />

  {/* Some other code, many more lines...  */}

</MyComponent>
```

So how can I jump to `</MyComponent>` when the cursor is within the first 4 lines of `<MyComponent>` and vice versa?

I already stumbled across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996522/jump-to-closing-tag-in-vs-code), but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> --> *"Emmet: Go to Matching Pair"* does not work.
Searching the Marketplace for an appropriate VS Code Extension also revealed no result.

Is it possible at all?

**Edit:**
Changed `<MyComponent>` to not be self-closing anymore.

Comment: There are extensions which highlight matching tags, I would go in this direction and forking it to create own extension. Or just use/learn VIM.

Comment: Before learning VIM, I'd rather learn a language that doesn't require <tags>. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example code the tag `MyComponent` is self-closing due to the forward slash on line 4. The Emmet command therefore remains on this tag rather than moving to line 8 as you are expecting.

Updated code snippet without the `MyComponent` tag being self-closing:

```
<MyComponent
  prop1="someValue"
  prop2={someOtherValue}
>
  <OtherComponent1 />

  {/* Some other code, many more lines...  */}

</MyComponent>
```

With this updated example <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then "Emmet: Go to Matching Pair" works correctly.

As suggested in the post you linked you can then add a keybinding for the command `editor.emmet.action.matchTag`.

Comment: Nice spotting!!  I wondered why the emmet command wouldn't work.

Comment: @ChrisC You're absolutely right. Now I'm completely puzzled! In my production code, the `<MyComponent>` tag was not self-closing, that was acutally a mistake I made when typing the sample code in my question. The "Go to matching pair" emmet never worked for me. But right now when I tried it again after reading your answer, it did work like a charm! Don't know what was wrong with my VS Code... Maybe some misbehaving extension...

Answer (score 0):

With the extension `multi-command` make a sequence of

- `Emmet: Balance outward`
- `Arrow Right`

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for - this solution would require two key bindings, one for the closing and one for the opening tag - but a nice workaround. Thanks.